# configuring gitlab with SSH support

Tags: ssl, nginx, gitlab

I am trying to setup gitlab on my server with SSL support. I am using a different port for the gitlab as follows in my nginx settings:

```
external_url 'https://myserver.com:2440
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
```

I also setup the SSL certificates as:

```
nginx['ssl_client_certificate'] = '/etc/ssl/AlphaSSLroot.crt'
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/ssl/org.crt'
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/ssl/org.key'
```

However, when I try to connect to my gitlab installation as `https://myserver.com:2440`, it comes back with the `server refused to connect error`. If I configure using `http`, it works.

I wonder if there is anything else I need to do to enable SSH here. I have my main website running on an apache web server using the same SSL certificate but on a completely different port (8080). So, I think I should be able to use the certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was because of the passphrase and I had to remove that using

```
openssl rsa -in www.key -out new.key
```

and use the `new.key` in nginx.